# Unable to print liquid variable values in Shopify

Tags: sass, shopify, liquid, shopify-app

I want to print the weight of variants in lbs and the quantity of variants of the products in the products page in Shopify. Here are the few things I am trying

This is the code inside js file:

Able to print the weight in grams:

```
 $('#variant-weight').text(variant_weight);
```

But I want to print in lbs something like this

```
$('#variant-weight').text({{ variant.weight | weight_with_unit: variant.weight_unit }});
```

For the above code I am not getting any output.

Also I want to print the quantity which is left, but not able to get the desired output. Here is the code:

```
$('.variant-sku').text(variant.inventory_quantity);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are miss matching JS and LIQUID wrongly.

Yes you can add liquid in JS files if the files have an extension of `.js.liquid` but in your case this is not doing you any good since you don't have direct access to the variant object.

Instead of using `{{ variant.weight | weight_with_unit: variant.weight_unit }}` in the JS, add this in the liquid files.

For example (assuming that you):

`<div id="variant-weight" data-weight="{{ variant.weight | weight_with_unit: variant.weight_unit }}"></div>`

And in the JS you can get data value if you need it.

**PS:**

Please note that once again you don't have direct access to the variant object. You must be in the `product.variants` loop or get something like `product.first_available_variant.weight` instead. And if you are in the variants loop please don't use an `ID` but a `class` instead.